# put command output into an array

Tags: arrays, bash

I want put the output of command into an array using bash

```
mylist=`ls -al`

# output
drwxr-xr-x   4 user  staff   128 Jan 30 17:42 .
drwxrwxr-x@ 37 user  staff  1184 Jan 30 16:32 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff  1164 Jan 30 17:42 somefile
```

Comment: Don't use `ls` for this at all. Use globs to get the file names you want, and use `stat` to get whatever information you need about each file.

Comment: ok, `ls` was only an example, i could use `top` or `ps` also...